# О словообразовании иностранцу

Tags: словообразование

Какое словообразование у слов: русско-казахский, платье-костюм, город-герой?

Answer (score 1):

Русско-казахский -- сложение основ слов с  соединительной гласной; 
платье-костюм, город-герой -- сложение основ слов без соединительной гласной (нулевой интерфикс).